# Exclude cells for cdf deployment

Tags: cdf-format, cells

I have a demonstration notebook with a code development chapter and a demonstration chapter with a manipulate environment, like this depicted minimal example

[image: Demonstration notebook]

I know how to export a cdf but is there any command to export the whole notebook **without** a specific section/chapter? I have been playing around with `Cells[CellStyle->"Chapter"]` , `SelectionMove[]` and `NotebookSelection[]` but without any luck. At the end I would like to have a cdf file only with the title, lecture information and the demonstration, i.e., **without** the code development chapter, like this

[image: What I want at the end]

Here you can get the notebook, if it is easier to test for you

[Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HppN1nEJ6KRFZ2bHRiSF9WYWs/view?usp=sharing)

Naturally, I know I can just create a copy file of the notebook, erase the code part and then manually create the cdf. But may be there is a command in order to avoid that procedure and do everything within one notebook using `CDFDeploy[]`. Thanks!

Comment: If there is no pattern of what you want to skip, I'd use CellTags to mark what is meant for deployment. Then you can automatically create duplicate output `NotebookLocate + NotebookDelete + Deploy + delete parent notebook` or something.

Comment: Thanks, the tags and `NotebookLocate` do the job without the need to delete anything. I will post the answer in a sec.

Comment: Even better, great ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Kuba's comment you can do what I wanted by selecting all cells but the ones that should be excluded, give them a tag with Ctrl+J, e.g., dep and use the following lines

```
NotebookLocate["dep"]
CDFDeploy[dir <> "demo2.cdf", NotebookSelection[], Method ->"Standalone"];
```

With that `NotebookLocate["dep"]` locates **and selects** all tagged cells, which are then used in `CDFDeploy[]` with `NotebookSelection[]`. You will see this in your current notebook like in this picture

[image: Selection of tagged cells]

and you will get a cdf only with the selected cells.